# Is there no admin ui guide for 4.x?

Tags: plugin-development, admin, css, user-interface

I'm starting a plugin project, and I want to keep the admin pages consistent with the rest of the admin in regard to styles and elements. However, I can't seem to find any resource that lists default admin style/patterns/elements for any recent versions. I've only found [WordPress Admin Pattern Library](https://github.com/helen/wp-style-guide) which is now 3 years old. Not sure if I'm just not able to find or if one doesn't exist. Like we have for bootstrap for example.

Is there no ui guide for admin area pages?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't exist. The closest thing is Helen Hou-Sandí's [WordPress Admin Pattern Library](https://github.com/helen/wp-style-guide), which you've already found. While it hasn't been updated in a few years, neither has the design of the WordPress admin, really.